# ASP.NET Loop XML not updating?

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, xpath

Got a massive problem with some XML. I've done a lot to do with reading XML but never actually written it and here is my XML document at the moment.

I've attached some photos of my XML and ASP.NET function to loop through but every time I loop through the notification.outerxml updates with the new date but the start and end date do not.

any ideas?

[image: XML Doc]

[image: My loop ASP.NET function]

[image: The problem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.//` instead of `//` to make an XPath that is relative to current context node, for example :

```
ldteStartDate = CDate(notification.SelectSingleNode(".//StartDate").InnerText)
```

`//` starts from the document's root, hence you always get the same first-matched element using such XPath axis with `SelectSingleNode()`.